# .NET System.Drawing.Font - Get Available Sizes and Styles

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, size, system.drawing

I have one combo that allows user to select a font name.

The 2nd is supposed to show available sizes of the font. The 3rd has to show available styles.

Question: how can I retrieve the sizes and styles selected System.Drawing.Font supports?

Comment: You would have to go back to Windows version 3 to find fonts that are only available in certain sizes.  Device fonts.  TrueType fonts can be rendered in any size.  And support synthesizing styles that are unavailable.  System.Drawing.Font only supports TrueType fonts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving available font sizes on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003450/retrieving-available-font-sizes-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [InstalledFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class to retrieve the available fonts and then enumerate them as shown [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

```
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();

// Get the array of FontFamily objects.
fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;

// The loop below creates a large string that is a comma-separated
// list of all font family names.

int count = fontFamilies.Length;
for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
{
    familyName = fontFamilies[j].Name;
    familyList = familyList + familyName;
    familyList = familyList + ",  ";
}
```

Comment: I already have working font name combo - but how can I get the sizes and styles the font supports?

Comment: `FontFamily` has a `IsStyleAvailable` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.isstyleavailable%28v=VS.90%29.aspx which returns a bool. Not sure about font size.

Comment: If it is an outline font (TrueType, etc.) then any size should be possible. I am not sure how that applies to bitmap fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a good-looking font family today, I use the below code to enumerate all font families, and print them in an image, so that it is easier to compare which looks good.

Shared below:

```
        Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(width: 1600, height: 8000);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage))
        {
            var imageRect = new Rectangle(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1600, height: 8000);

            System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
            FontFamily[] fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;

            var format = new StringFormat();
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;

            int verticalOffset = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < fontFamilies.Length; ++j)
            {
                using (var font = new Font(fontFamilies[j].Name, 40, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
                {
                    // Height
                    var textSize = g.MeasureString(fontFamilies[j].Name, font);
                    int textWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Width + 10);
                    int textHeight = (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Height + 10);

                    // Draw text
                    Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(x: j % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 800, y: verticalOffset, width: textWidth, height: textHeight);
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackgroundColor), textRect);
                    g.DrawString(fontFamilies[j].Name, font, new SolidBrush(PercentageTextColor), textRect, format);
                    g.Save();

                    if (j % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        verticalOffset += textHeight;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        bitmapImage.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);


        // then do whatever you like with this bitmapImage, save it to local, etc.
```