# Easiest way to change font and font size

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

which is the easiest way to change Font size with C#.

with java it can all be done easily by calling Font constructor with necessary arguments.

```
JLabel lab  = new JLabel("Font Bold at 24");
lab.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 24));
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
yourformName.YourLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
```

Or if you are in the same class as the form then simply do this:

```
YourLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
```

The constructor takes diffrent parameters (so pick your poison). Like this:

```
Font(Font, FontStyle)   
Font(FontFamily, Single)
Font(String, Single)
Font(FontFamily, Single, FontStyle)
Font(FontFamily, Single, GraphicsUnit)
Font(String, Single, FontStyle)
Font(String, Single, GraphicsUnit)
Font(FontFamily, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit)
Font(String, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit)
Font(FontFamily, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte)
Font(String, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte)
Font(FontFamily, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte, Boolean)
Font(String, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte, Boolean)
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx)

Comment: Long time no talk - but you didn't dispose the old font - if you'll do that a lot of times - you might run out of GDI handles. Am I right?

Answer (score 35):

Use this one to change only font size not the name of the font

```
label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(label1.Font.Name, 24F);
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the [Font Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx) to set the control's font and styles.

Try [Font Constructor (String, Single)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z.aspx)

```
Label lab  = new Label();
lab.Text ="Font Bold at 24";
lab.Font = new Font("Arial", 20);
```

or

```
lab.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,
            12.0F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

To get installed fonts refer this - [.NET System.Drawing.Font - Get Available Sizes and Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661181/net-system-drawing-font-get-available-sizes-and-styles)

Answer (score 7):

This should do it (bold as well);

```
label1.Font = new Font("Serif", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a varible and then assign it for a text. It is cool because you can assign it two or more texts.

**To assign a variable do that**

```
public partial class Sayfa1 : Form

   Font Normal = new Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

    public Sayfa1()
```

This varible is not assigned to any text yet.To do it write the name of the text(Look proporties -> (Name)) then write ".Font" then call the name of your font variable.

```
lupusToolStripMenuItem.Font = Normal;
```

Now you have a text assigned to a Normal font. I hope I could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can change that using label property in property panel.
[This screen shot is example that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03kyY.png)