# Changing the font size of a character with insert

Tags: c#, winforms, insert

how would I change the font size of the "_" in the Word.Insert?

```
string Word = "yellow";
 Word.Insert(2, " _ ");
```

Comment: `string`s don't have font sizes?

Comment: @OutlawLemur Even if I placed it in a Label?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is in a Label (from comments):

```
yourformName.YourLabel.Content = Word;
yourformName.YourLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", fontSize ,FontStyle.Bold);
```

See [Easiest way to change font and font size with visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173147/easiest-way-to-change-font-and-font-size-with-visual-c-sharp)